# Painting Stroked/Bordered Text on Canvas

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, flutter-canvas

I'm trying to paint stroked text on a canvas. in my editor, I created the stroked text effect by stacking two text widegts:

```dart
class TextDataView extends ElementView<TextData> {

  final String placeholderText;

  TextDataView(TextData data, {required this.placeholderText}) : super(data);

  Text buildText(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data.text.isNotEmpty ? data.text : placeholderText,
      style: data.getTextStyle(),
      textAlign: data.textAlignment,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text = buildText(context);
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        // for outline
        Text(
          text.data!,
          style: text.style!.copyWith(
            foreground: Paint()
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
              ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
              ..strokeWidth = data.textStrokeSize
              ..color = data.textStrokeSize == 0
                  ? Colors.transparent
                  : data.textStrokeColor,
            color: null,
          ),
          maxLines: text.maxLines,
          overflow: text.overflow,
          semanticsLabel: text.semanticsLabel,
          softWrap: text.softWrap,
          strutStyle: text.strutStyle,
          textAlign: text.textAlign,
          textDirection: text.textDirection,
          textScaleFactor: text.textScaleFactor,
        ),
        // for display
        text,
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

For output rendering, I can only paint the display text:

```dart
extension TextDataToTextPainter on TextData {
  TextPainter composeText() {
    return TextPainter(
      textAlign: textAlignment,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      maxLines: maxLines,
      textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: getTextStyle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class EditorTextPainter extends ElementPainter<TransformData<TextData>> {
  @override
  Future<void> draw(Canvas canvas, Size size, TransformData<TextData> data) {
    canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());

    final text = data.data.composeText();
    final offset = data.offset.alongSize(size);
    final textSize = data.size.toActualSize(size);

    text.layout(maxWidth: textSize.width);
    text.paint(canvas, offset);

    canvas.rotate(data.angle);
    canvas.restore();

    return Future.value();
  }
}
```

How can I also paint the stroke with `TextPainter`?

Answer (score 0):

I Can just paint the border text before the display text